# Gutenberg template lock but add/delete blocks programmatically

Tags: block-editor

I am using the [templateLock](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/#template) property to lock down the template of an inner block:

```
edit: () => {
     return (
         <InnerBlocks
             template={ MY_TEMPLATE }
             templateLock="all"
         />
     );
 },
```

I am not allowing to insert new blocks or delete them.

However I would like to add or delete blocks programmatically, for example using:

```
wp.data.dispatch("core/block-editor").removeBlock( blockClientId );
```

This does not work because the template lock prevents all operations. Is it possible to lock the template but still be able to add/delete the child blocks programmatically?

I know it is possible to lock individual blocks with the new [lock attribute](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/01/08/locking-blocks-in-wordpress-5-9/), but this adds a lock icon to the blocks, also the possibility to uncheck locking. I do not want the user to see any add or delete block UI, or be confused by the lock icon.

Comment: I couldn't find a standard way of doing this, but I think you can use a custom (and private) block attribute, e.g. `_lockTemplate`, and basically set it to false when you want to programmatically add/remove a child block, then set it to true afterwards. Or have you already found a (different) solution?

Comment: @SallyCJ, i did not find another solution. I was also thinking about turning on and off template lock when needed. However I did not know there are private block attributes. Are you able to please post your solution as an answer? This may be the only solution available.

Comment: There aren't any "private attributes", and by "private", I simply meant an attribute with a name that starts with `_` (underscore) which is normally treated as private. And after a 2nd thought, I think you could actually use state and just modify the `template` value to add or delete child blocks. Would you like to see an example?

Comment: @SallyCJ an example would definitely help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a standard way to do this, but as I commented, an easy way to do it is by using a state which will store either the initial template you set or the inner blocks (i.e. their names and attributes) that were *already added* to the parent block. Which basically means, you will pass conditional `template` to the `InnerBlocks` component.

**Working Example**

1. WordPress dependencies specific to this example, in addition to `InnerBlocks` etc.

   ```js
   import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';
   import { useState } from '@wordpress/element';
   import { Button } from '@wordpress/components'; // for the demos; see below
   ```
2. Now here's the `edit()` function where I added 2 buttons for testing the functionality you wanted to have:

   ```js
   function edit( { clientId } ) {
       const innerBlocks = useSelect( select => {
           const { getBlocks } = select( 'core/block-editor' );
           return getBlocks( clientId );
       }, [ clientId ] );

       // If there are no inner blocks yet, use the initial template. Else, we use
       // the name and attributes of each (immediate) child block.
       const _template = ( innerBlocks.length < 1 ) ? MY_TEMPLATE :
           innerBlocks.map( block => [ block.name, block.attributes ] );

       // Add a state which ensures React re-renders our block when the template is
       // changed.
       const [ template, setTemplate ] = useState( _template );

       // Demo callback which adds a child block.
       const demoInsertChildBlock = () => // wrapped
           setTemplate( [ ...template, [ 'core/quote', {} ] ] );

       // Demo callback which removes a child block.
       const demoRemoveChildBlock = () => {
           const newTemplate = [ ...template ]; // copy current template
           newTemplate.pop();                   // remove the last child
           setTemplate( newTemplate );
       };

       return (
           <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
               Hello from the editor!

               <InnerBlocks
                   template={ template }
                   templateLock="all"
               />

               <Button text="Insert demo block" variant="primary" onClick={ demoInsertChildBlock } />
               <span>&nbsp;</span>
               <Button text="Remove last block" variant="primary" onClick={ demoRemoveChildBlock } />
           </div>
       );
   }
   ```

   So as you could see, you just need to call `setTemplate()` function to add/remove a child block.

Comment: PS: If you wanted to actually add/remove a child block **before** the element is rendered, then you may not need the state at all... but I thought you wanted to add/remove child blocks only after the element is rendered? Additionally, I defined `MY_TEMPLATE` outside the `edit()` function, however it shouldn't be a problem even if you (need to) define the constant inside that function.

Comment: Thank you this is brilliant

Comment: But this only allows removing the last block, you can't remove blocks in the middle?

Comment: @riv removing the last child is just an example. Presumably there's nothing stopping you from modifying or recreating the template however you see fit